# find chair in survivor problem

Tags: puzzle

> Complete Question Text: Take a second to imagine that you are in a
>   room with 100 chairs arranged in a circle. These chairs are numbered
>   sequentially from One to One Hundred.
>
> At some point in time, the person in chair #1 will be told to leave
>   the room. The person in chair #2 will be skipped, and the person in
>   chair #3 will be told to leave. Next to go is person in chair #6. In
>   other words, 1 person will be skipped initially, and then 2, 3, 4..
>   and so on. This pattern of skipping will keep going around the circle
>   until there is only one person remaining.. the survivor. Note that the
>   chair is removed when the person leaves the room.

***Question is: Find out which chair the survivor is sitting in?***

How do we solve this problem? Any explanation/walk through will help me a lot.

Comment: This is called the Josephus problem.  Wikipedia has a complete [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).